# Fresh Laravel install displays 403 Forbidden in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, laravel, centos

I have created a fresh Laravel application by using `composer create-project` command. Then I put all the folders and files in `/usr/share/nginx/html/`, which is the default document root for my nginx server. However everytime I runs the `http://localhost`, it keeps displaying `403 Forbiden`. I tried creating a testing `index.php (<? php_info();)` and it worked fine.

I've read somewhere that I need to set the containing folder (/html), as well as the `app/storage` folder permission to 777 but still no luck.

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Here is the nginx [default.conf](https://gist.github.com/hoanglamhuynh/7e1fc25d585d10d1cabd)

Comment: 403 is probably because the config is pointing to a folder and that folder doesn't contain an index, so nginx tries to list the directory, but because autoindex is off, so it returns a forbidden error, pasting your config would help us help you.

Answer (score 8):

Laravel projects serve from the `<projectName>/public` directory. Make sure your nginx config is set up to look there for your index file and NOT in your `<projectName>` folder only.

Answer (score 5):

Would you edit your question and paste your server config there?

I think it may because index.php is not in the index file list. check these lines:

```
index index.html index.php;
```

or

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct - Laravel services from the `public` folder and you need to tell nginx to look there - but also a little vague if you're bumping up against this problem. When you create new sites on a Homestead installation by adding them to your .yaml file and using `vagrant provision` or `vagrant up --provision`, the created nginx conf file will need editing before Laravel will serve files correctly.

Go to your CLI, and enter Homestead using `vagrant ssh` or `homestead ssh`. It will ask for your password, which by default is "vagrant".

Once you're in the virtual machine, type the following commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your-site-name-here
```

Then add `/public` to the end of the existing root near the top of the file (it'll be something like `/home/vagrant/projects/your-site` to begin with and save in Nano (ctrl+s), then exit nano (ctrl+x).

Once you've exited Nano, restart nginx using `sudo nginx -s reload`. Your routing will now work!